# radeon 0000:1:00.0: vce init error (-110)

Tags: radeon, init

After i upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 the boot screen freezes at this error and i can do nothing!

> radeon 0000:1:00.0: vce init error (-110)

Comment: I am also experiencing this.